# How to find the highest number of a column and print two columns of that row in R?

Tags: r, dataset, max

How do get the highest value of **column2** then print **column1** AND **column2** of that row?

```
Column1 Column2
test1    2
test2    9
test3    3
test5    4.5
```

So, how do I print the second row since **column 2** has the highest value?

**Remember that there are more columns in the data set but I don't wanna print them all.**

**EDIT:**
Already tried getting the highest value of that column but I would like to print two columns of that row (not all columns); the one below gives me the entire row which contains around 35 columns:

```
subset(df1, Column2 == max(Column2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `slice`  - returns the first row where the `max` value is found

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  select(Column1, Column2) %>%
  slice(which.max(Column2))
```

---

Or with `subset` from `base R` - returns all rows where the `max` value is present

```
subset(df1, Column2 == max(Column2), select = c(Column1, Column2))
```

Or with `which.max` - returns the first row where the max value is found

```
df1[which.max(df1$Column2),c("Column1", "Column2"), drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: That's what I tried already but I would like to print only two columns, as I have stated I have many columns. So, get highest value of column2 and print Column1 and Column2 of that row.

Comment: @CoolSolutions thank you for explaning.  I updated the post by adding the `select` in between